# Force sourcetree git ssh through proxy under windows

Tags: git, ssh, proxy, windows-10, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using sourcetree under windows10 and interact with remote git repo through ssh.

I want sourcetree to interact with remote git repo through local socks proxy that I start with Putty.

There are many solutions but are all for Linux, how can I achieve this under windows10 with sourcetree? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in your previous question, do not use Putty. At all.

Use only openssh which comes with [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (`C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe`)

You can then establish  the same tunnel  (as [shown here](https://superuser.com/a/1342227/141)) using that ssh:

```
ssh -D 8123 -f -C -q -N socksserverip.com
```

Once that is working, you can try and use the tunnel in SourceTree.